# Show Popup on ajax autocomplete listitem hover

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an autocompletelist. 
I want to show modelpopup window on autocompletelistitem hover.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can just use jquery  [Hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Provide some code snippet so that anyone can understand what you exactly want.